# Drools Decision table for symptom reporting

Tags: drools

We're in the process of implementing a symptom reporting decision tree: patients answers questions about whether a symptom is present or not, and in the end , the reported symptoms lead to an outcome. Mapping the symptoms to an outcome can be achieved with a guided decision table.

The goal is to reach an outcome by asking as few questions as possible; there will be 10+ symptoms, but if patient reports a fever in combination with a headache, the other symptoms don't matter. The question is: how could we implement this as such that Drools determines which question needs to be asked?

Answer (score 0):

For a certain diagnosis, the minimum number of questions can only be asked if the diagnosis is known before you ask the questions.

On the average, asking questions where a positive answer halves the number of possibilities should reduce the number of remaining options as fast as possible. Thus, count the marks in a column, and order them by the absolute difference of the count from m, where m is half the number of rows or diagnoses.

(Absolutely th best way would be to have a doctor look at the patient up front.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Users call and answer the prerecorded questions by pressing a number on their phone. Based on the matched symptoms the advice will be played to the patient like come to clinic etc. My questions is how could we implement this as such that Drools determines which question needs to be asked

Comment: I have understood your question, and I think I answered it.